# Running 32 bit application in 64 bit server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, 32bit-64bit

We have developed a web application . It contains large amount of Data .So I need to enable 64 bit  application in IIS application Pool (ie . Disable 32 bit application ). I have some regression due to enabling the 64 bit. I have added some dll with 32 pit application .Now its not running. Is there any solution to run 32 bit application in 64 bit application. Is there any work around process to resolve this regression.

advance in thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is typical issue when you have to use 32-bit DLL in your project. The solution is dead simple - move 32-bit code out into separate process and communicate to it with any means you're familiar with. I prefer WCF with named pipe binding - the fastest option within the same machine.